# How to organize daily logging files in Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using Logback for logging. Now all logs are writing into one file, and it becomes very large. How to organize logging in such a way that a new file is created at the beginning of a new day?

I use such logback.xml

```xml
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n" />
    <property name="APP_LOG_ROOT" value="admin-logs"/>

    <timestamp key="year" datePattern="yyyy" />
    <timestamp key="month" datePattern="MM" />
    <timestamp key="date" datePattern="dd" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger level="INFO" name="my.name">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: That depends on the logging implementation that you are using. SLF4J is just an API, and Lombok a convenience framework to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

> all logs are writing into one file

The shown config is going to the STDOUT, not a file.

If you want to write to a daily file, use `logrotate`/`cron` process, or have logback do this itself.

```
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/app.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/bim.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    ...
</appender>
```

...

```
    <logger level="INFO" name="my.name">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
```